# Doctrine 2.6.1: OnFlush Event, error when create new entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

According to [the onFlush event documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#onflush), the following code is valid:

```
foreach ($uow->getScheduledEntityInsertions() as $entity) {
    if ($entity instanceof Site) {

        $siteStatus = new SiteStatusHistory();
        $siteStatus->setSite($entity);
        $siteStatus->setStatus($entity->getBillingStatus());

        $manager->persist($siteStatus);
        $uow->computeChangeSet($manager->getClassMetadata(SiteStatusHistory::class), $siteStatus);
    }
}
```

When using doctrine 2.5 everything is fine, but after switching to 2.6.1 I have an error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'site_id' cannot be null (Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\NotNullConstraintViolationException)
```

I already search on StackOverflow/Google but I didn't find anything because Doctrine 2.6 has just been released recently.

I quickly checked the release notes (for 2.6 and 2.6.1) but I didn't anything either.

EDIT: the problem appear only on behat test, not in dev or prod env